# ngOptions with Objects won't populate

Tags: angularjs, ng-options

I have a select dropdown I'd like to populate with the names of users in objects:

```
        <select id="entityDropDown" 
            ng-model="selectedUser" 
            ng-options="user as user.name for user in users" 
            ng-change="getUserInfo(selectedUser)">
        </select>
```

My object is structured as such:

```
users:  { 
    1:  { 
        name: Demo Administrator,
        id: 1,
        domain: null,
        email: null,
        isAdmin: False,
     },
    4:  { 
        name: ITUN\WSS,
        id: 4,
        domain: i:0#.f|admembers|,
        email: ,
        isAdmin: False,
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the comprehension expression for objects:

```
ng-options="user as user.name for (key,user) in users"
```

Comment: thanks, that worked perfect. I keep reading the docs on ngOptions but their examples aren't very good if your not using an array.

Answer (score 0):

In your case `users` is not an array.

So instead of

```
users:  { 
  1: { 
     name: Demo Administrator
     id: 1
     domain: ITUN\demoadmin_compulite
     email: simkessy@gmail.com
     isAdmin: False
     } 
}
```

You want something like this

```
users:  [ 
   { 
     name: Demo Administrator
     id: 1
     domain: ITUN\demoadmin_compulite
     email: simkessy@gmail.com
     isAdmin: False
     } ,
     { 
     name: Demo Administrator
     id: 2
     domain: ITUN\demoadmin_compulite
     email: simkessy@gmail.com
     isAdmin: False
     } 
]
```

Comment: Is there anyway to use an ngOptions with objects. I do a lot of comparing and retrieval using objects. If I change it to an array, it complicates things a bit.

Comment: You can not iterate over a single complex object without some custom code.

Comment: @Batman How does your object look like with more than one users?

Comment: I've updated OP to add another object. If I need custome code, I'll probably revert back to user arrays of objects. I'd like to stick as close as possible to Angular.

Comment: @Batman It doesn't look like a valid JSON. It should have comma after each field. There are no commas after name, id, etc...Also String should be under quote.

Comment: It's not JSON, it's an object literal. I've copying over the result from Batarang which doesn't display the commas for some reason but it's definitely an object.